# JQuery Scroll Speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get an image to scroll slower than other elements on a site with the div class slow-image however the JQuery doesn't seem to do anything. Does anyone know why?

CSS:

```
.slow-image
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 25vw;
    top: 10vw;
    margin-left: 60vw;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slow-image"><img src="..."></div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $win = $(window);

    $('slow-image').each(function(){
        var scroll_speed = 0.8; 
        var $this = $(this);
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var bgScroll = -(($win.scrollTop() - $this.offset().top)/ scroll_speed);
            var bgPosition = 'center '+ bgScroll + 'px';
            $this.css({ backgroundPosition: bgPosition });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: why do you have ( - ) operator after `var bgScroll = `?

Comment: `$('slow-image')` should be `$('.slow-image')` and setting the backgroundPosition won't do anything because you have an img element instead of backgroundImage. And it looks like you are trying to achieve a parallax effect. There are lots of tutorial and plugins for creating parallax effect, try googling it.